# log.retention and cleanup.policy - Spring Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have the following configuration in my `docker-compose.yml`

```
kafka:
    image: 'confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.1.0'
    hostname: kafka
    container_name: kafka
    ports:
      - '9092:9092'
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://127.0.0.1:9092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_LICENSE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_BALANCER_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_MINUTES: 5
      KAFKA_LOG_CLEANUP_POLICY: compact, delete
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
```

I'm using Spring Kafka Binder Streams for creating Topics. Once the application is up, I can see the topics in kafka but I dont see `log.retention.minutes` or `cleanup.policy` for the config.

it works if I specify the configuration for a specific topic. Is it not possible to configure log retention and cleanup at broker level?

```
    @Bean
    public NewTopic crateEmployeeTopic() {
        return TopicBuilder
                .name(KafkaConfig.EMP_DATA_TOPIC)
                .partitions(3)
                .config(TopicConfig.RETENTION_MS_CONFIG, "90000")
                .config(TopicConfig.CLEANUP_POLICY_CONFIG, "compact, delete")
                .build();
    }
```

-- UPDATE --

I was using Kafdrop UI to check the topic config. It was showing configs when it was defined at topic level , but at the broker level it is not showing any config. I ran the `describe` command to double check and can now see `cleanup.policy`, but `retention` is still missing

```
$ kafka-topics --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe -- topic  emp_data
Topic: emp_data    PartitionCount: 3      ReplicationFactor: 1    Configs: cleanup.policy=compact,delete
        Topic: emp_data   Partition: 0    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: _but I dont see log.retention.minutes or cleanup.policy for the config._ - What are you using to check those values?

Comment: Thank you. updated the question. @OneCricketeer. In short ```describe topic``` shows ``config.policy`` but ``retention`` is still missing.

Comment: The broker defaults never have shown up with that command. You can use `kafka-configs.sh`, I think instead

Comment: That worked. Thank you! Adding ```kafka-configs.sh``` command as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can set broker config for `log.retention.minutes` as mentioned in [here](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs_log.retention.minutes).
Then all topics that config defaults to it.

`cleanup.policy` is also same. [Read here](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs_log.cleanup.policy) for more information.

Comment: yes, I was referring those links to setup the configuration.

Comment: when you are setting up these configurations, they are broker config and default to topic configs. So they are not specific for the topic. That's why they not showing in topic level.

Comment: thank you. I had to use ```kafaka-config.sh``` command.

Answer (score 0):

this command did the trick.

```
$ kafka-configs --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --entity-type brokers --entity-name 1 --all --describe | grep retention
```